# Why is tensorflow installation failing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm attempting to install tensorflow using the conda install tensoflow command.

However, the installation appears to fail when attempting to uninstall numpy.

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::numpy-1.14.0-py36h4a99626_1'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')

does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `sudo chown -R user anaconda3` and try again.

- Check out : [conda update permission error](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3448)